# Cordova/Phonegap iOS - how to start app's index.html from external Documents folder

Tags: ios, cordova

We're trying to implement updating of webapp assets without updating application itself.

I download assets to Documents/some/path/name folder and trying to start application from this folder.

But app log displays that `.../Documents/..../index.html` is not found.

Here is my code sample:

```
NSString *wwwFolderName = @"web";

if ([directoryList count] > 0) {
    NSArray *sortedDirectoryList = [directoryList sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSString *latestVersionFolder = [sortedDirectoryList objectAtIndex:([sortedDirectoryList count] - 1)];
    wwwFolderName = [appDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:latestVersionFolder];
}

// end of assets directory initialization


self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;
self.viewController.wwwFolderName = wwwFolderName;
self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";
```

How can I start cordova app from Documents' app specific folder?

```
downloaded assets path: /var/mobile/Applications/{App-HASH}/Documents/revisions/123/
```

This is what Orgamizer log displays:

```
ERROR: Start Page at '/var/mobile/Applications/10E317FA-CD51-4DD1-A07D-3C69EB4C5342/Documents/appname/790/index.html' was not found.
```